# How to get jmap histogram programmatically?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, jvm-hotspot, heap-dump

I would like to get the equivalent of the ouput of `jmap -histo` programmatically, from inside the monitored application. I see triggering a heap dump is possible through the HotSpot diagnostic bean, but I can't see how to get the histogram data. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be not the best example/code, but have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/source/browse/trunk/javamelody-core/src/main/java/net/bull/javamelody/VirtualMachine.java#130)

(I think it's only working on Hotspot JVMs)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess this means there is no "internal" way to do this, you have to anyhow attach an agent to get this information ?

Comment: This is an internal way (it's not executing the jmap application), but it's not a jvm-independent way, because non-standardized classes/methods are used, which do not even exist in other jvm implementations.

Comment: It's not internal, it attaches an agent externally.

Comment: Looks like it is ultimately invoking e.g. `sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.heapHisto("-all")` (via reflection of course), though you have to call `VirtualMachine.attach($myOwnPID)` first. Not clear this is much preferable to just running the `jmap` executable.